# ASP.NET WAP, register user with manual approval

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project, user-registration

I'm new to ASP.NET.

On a web site, I want users to be able to register, their input data to be saved in a database, but their login should not be functional until their data has been reviewed and potentially approved. The database would then be updated with a new entry with their login and details.

I think it makes sense to have the registration details and the user details as separate tables. As the user details will have many additional fields. So registration and login should connect to different tables.

Does this sound sensible?  And would I in this case have any benefit from using the **CreateUserWizard** and **Login** controls? Will it allow me to specify the custom database and fields for handling registration data and user status?

If not, it would be nice if you could give some rough steps on how I should approach this "manually"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using ASP.Net Membership object, once user is created make sure you override `IsApproved` property to 1, this will stop user from login in until you review it and set `IsApproved` property = 0.